# Import data file compressed with .zstd

Tags: r, data.table

I want to import data using fread but the dataset I want to import is compressed with zstd.

I know that with gzip for example I can do something like

```
ds <- fread('zcat file.csv.gz')
```

Is it possible to do something similar for zstd?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zstdcat` is equivalent to `zcat` for `.zst` files

Comment: Thank you very much! That was easier than expected

Comment: @ Cyan: Could you please show an example as to how we would import this file into R? thanks!